# How to import large SPSS fails without turning it in to a large list?

Tags: r, import, spss

I have a large SPSS fail with 12 variables and about 1,7 million rows. I am importing the fail as follows:

```
library(foreign)
DF_2020 <- read.spss("D:/data/DF 2020.sav")
```

This imports the fail in a Large list view. This is the first time i am seeing it. How can I import the data as a .sav fail and convert it in to a normal format?

If i export the data from SPSS as .CSV and then import the .CSV it works.

Am i using a wrong library?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't well understand what you mean by "normal format", but I assume you want a data frame format:

```
library(foreign)

DF_2020 <- read.spss("D:/data/DF 2020.sav",to.data.frame = TRUE)
```

Comment: You assumed correctly :) Thank you this fixed it for me.